# ActionController::ParameterMissing in LoansController#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know there are lots of these errors discussed and I have read many of them with no success so this is not a first step by posting. I am a developer but new to Ruby so any guidance would be appreciated thanks!

I have 2 models Loan and Growthyear and Loan has_many :growthyears

Existing loans are displaying and I can edit them but trying to create a new Loan now gets this error ever since I added the nested association growthyears.

I can post the new.html.erb but I don't believe it is even getting that far.

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in LoansController#new
param is missing or the value is empty: loan

Extracted source (around line #249):

        value
      else
        raise ParameterMissing.new(key)
      end
    end
```

loan.rb

```
class Loan < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :growthyears 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :growthyears, reject_if: proc { |attributes|      attributes['growth'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
end
```

growthyear.rb

```
class Growthyear < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :loan
  validates_presence_of :growth
end
```

loans_controller.rb

```
class LoansController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @loan = Loan.find(params[:id])
  end

  def home
  end

  def destroy
    Loan.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Loan (" + params[:id]  + ") deleted " + Time.now.localtime("+10:00").to_s
    redirect_to loans_url
  end

  def index
    @loans = Loan.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 5)
  end

  def new
    @loan = Loan.new(user_params)
    @loan.growthyears.build
  end

  def create
    @loan = Loan.new(user_params)    # Not the final implementation!
    if @loan.save
      flash[:success] = "(" + @loan.id.to_s + ") " + @loan.name + " New Loan Saved! " + Time.now.localtime("+10:00").to_s
      render 'edit'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @loan = Loan.find(params[:id])
    @loan.yeargrowth = params[:yearlygrowth]
    if @loan.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "(" + @loan.id.to_s + ") " + @loan.name + " Loan updated " + Time.now.localtime("+10:00").to_s
    end
    redirect_to edit_loan_path(@loan.id)
  end

  def edit
    @loan = Loan.find(params[:id])
    flash[:success] = "(" + @loan.id.to_s + ") " + @loan.name + " Loan retrieved " + Time.now.localtime("+10:00").to_s
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:loan).permit(:name, :CCV, :Loan, :IRV, :ODV, :period, :simLowInt, :simHighInt, :bSimActive, :LoanBook, growthyears_attributes: [:growth, :id, :_destroy] )
    end
end
```

Comment: What is `:Loan` in your permitted parameters list? Is it a field in the `loans` table?

Comment: Yes not the best naming convention given its the same as the model but its a column in the loans table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should declare only Loan.new, because in new you only initliazie this object so instead this

```
 def new
    @loan = Loan.new(user_params)
    @loan.growthyears.build
  end
```

put this:

```
 def new
    @loan = Loan.new
    @loan.growthyears.build
  end
```

Comment: OMG so simple after days of looking at this!! Thanks @Gladis that fixed it

Comment: I gather thats done by the tick ? Do I mark this question as closed some way? thanks